# Can't get link light on HDS 9585v SAN management ports

Tags: storage-area-network

Have a Hitachi HDS 9585 Thunder that was moved and left to sit.  It doesn't appear to boot up fully as I never can see link lights on the ethernet ports we have plugged in.

Am I missing something?  Is there a way to reinitialize this beast?  There are no serial ports.

The configuration has changed, went from 10 shelves last bootup to now just 2.

Would I be getting a controller alarm because of the shelve configuration change?

Any help appreciated.  Hitachi doesn't let out this info without paying massive support costs.

Answer (score 1):

```
The configuration has changed, went from 10 shelves last bootup to now just 2.
```

Did you perhaps remove a shelf that held the systems OS?

I know on NetApp's the primary OS is stored on disk, and in fact you can't remove any disks (let alone shelves) where they're assigned to the same "aggregate" (disk pool) as the OS.

In any case there's a good chance the OS is not loading either because it can't, or to prevent data loss.

Are you sure there's no serial port? That's really weird.

Comment: This is almost certainly correct, he/she will have to get HDS involved to reinitialise the system I believe.